# Inheritance and my example. Which output?

Tags: java

I have a problem:

```java
class A {
    int x = 5;
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.print(a.x);
    }
}
```

I do not understand why 5 is displayed. Variable `a` has a new object `B` 
- `new B()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'shadowed' your variable `x` by redeclaring it in a subclass with the same name. When accessing an object of type `B` as an object of type `A`, you will reference class `A`'s attribute `x` - if you access it as what it is (an object of type `B`, you will get the correct value. Other than methods (where you can override behavior), you can not override fields (attributes) in the same way. If you modify your example, you will see the problem:

```java
static class A {
    int x = 5;

    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    int x = 10;

    @Override
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

@Test
public void main() {
    B b = new B();
    // this is the same instance as b, but we access it as a.
    A a = b;

    System.out.println(a.x); // 5
    System.out.println(b.x); // 10

    System.out.println(a.getX()); // 10
    System.out.println(b.getX()); // 10

    System.out.println(((B) a).x); // also 10, but bulky
}
```

This shows, how the different fields named `x` can be accessed, and when they are accessed. Your object of type `B` actually has two fields named `x`, one declared by class `A` and one declared by class `B`.

You should not try to reuse a taken name of a field. If you want the value to be different, you should instead have `B` modify the value of `A` in the constructor (if possible, as in your example):

```java
class A {
    int x = 5;
}

class B extends A {
    B () {
        x = 10; // this will change the value of `x` instead of redeclaring it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A a = new B();
```

This line implies your are creating a new class of B but you will only be using the methods/vars of its super class A.

You can simply access the methods/vars of B by type casting.

```
B b = (B) a;
```

example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new B();
    B b = (B) a;

    System.out.println(a.x);
    // prints 5
    System.out.println(b.x);
    // prints 10

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because even though you might have instaited it as `new B();` you named the type of the variable `A` which is an object and it is the superclass so it will print out `5` instead of 10.

Now if you wanted 10 then just do:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        B a = new B();
        System.out.print(b.x);
    }
}
```